# How can I apply sort of epsilon in my SQL querying command?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with two float columns. I want to find the equalities between my column 1 and my column 2 "to the nearest 10^-3".

For example 0.003672839 and 0.003861107 would be returned positively.

Is there a way to do this? Using `cast()` maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag the question with the RDBMS you're using. A sample query would also help. I would imagine most engines don't support anything more than an explicit `WHERE ABS(column1 - column2) < 0.0001)` or suchlike.

Comment: You could round both columns to the required precision and then compare them